# Conditionally bind a property in Angular2/4

Tags: angular

I want that a *placeholder* property (or any other) only gets into the DOM if it is defined. I tried

```
<textarea ... [placeholder]="value || null/false/undefined...etc" ... </textarea>
```

but these only show up as null, false, etc... as the text field's placeholder if value is not defined or null. (I know I could do `"value || ' '"` which would work for *placeholders*, but I'm looking for a more universal solution to keep any undefined property from getting into the DOM -as if `[property]="...` wouldn't be there at all.)

Why do I need this? Because my forms should be dynamic as *placeholder* and other attributes come from an interface and they don't necessarily have to be defined when they reach my template.

Comment: You could us ng-if https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff

Comment: With <textarea ... placeholder={{value}}...> you can skip  || ' '  option :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create directive that will contain logic for setting `placeholder` attribute on host element:

```typescipt
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[placeholder]'
})
export class PlaceholderDirective {
  @Input() placeholder;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.placeholder) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'placeholder', this.placeholder);
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'placeholder');
    }
  }
}
```

or we can simplify this directive like:

```typescipt
@Directive({
  selector: '[placeholder]'
})
export class PlaceholderDirective {
  @HostBinding('attr.placeholder') @Input() placeholder;
}
```

But you can always use attribute binding in your template:

```typescipt
<textarea [attr.placeholder]="null"></textarea>
```

Comment: If there's no easier template-only solution for that, this seems to be a clean one too, just one more question: Do I need to create so many *.ts files as the number of directives I want to describe this way? Or can I put the whole thing into the *.ts file belonging to the given template and define everything there like `@Directive({ selector: ['[placeholder]', '[checked]', '[rows]', etc... ] })` (or something like that) with multiple "export class"es underneath...? Or separate files are the only option?

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple selectors like `selector: '[placeholder],[checked]'`